# resize images in android

Tags: java, android

I want to resize my images (original size is 1080p) but they don't resize properly and I don't know why. The Images just don't have the right size sometimes. On my emulator and my old 800*480 smartphone it works fine but on my nexus 4 with 1280*768 things don't look right. There is no problem reading the right screen resolution. There is just a bug with my resize procedure. Please help me. Heres a Snippet:

```
private Bitmap bitmap,bitmap1;
private float factor;

WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
    height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;

factor = (float)height/1080; 

Int bitmapheight,bitmapwidth;
bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.picture),(int)(factor*BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.picture).getwidth() ,(int)(factor*BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.picture).getHeight(), true);

canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap,.....
```

In the end the height is not resized to 768/1080*bitmapheight on my nexus and i don't know why. Note everything else works. Mathmatics indicates that the height should be the same on every phone.

These are screenshots of my programm showing the images have not the same height

First image:

[image]

Second:

[image]

As you can see the Images are not equal in terms of height. On my emulator and my old smartphone they look right. The Images should not touch the bottom but on my nexus 4 they do touch the bottom.

Comment: You create a scaled bitmap from an image in resource using dimensions of which other bitmap?

Comment: i edited to make it more clear. I used the dimensions of the picture for bitmapwidth and bitmapheight.

Comment: Of which picture? The same as from the resource? Then why extract it twice? Show completer code please.

Comment: Are your images 1080x1080?

Comment: no they are completely different but they are scaled for 1080p. The one on the pictures is 464*966. That calculation the programm now basically does is 966/1080*768 (768 for my phone height) now that is 686 height for the picture but for some reason on my nexus it is much more and thats why the image doesnt fit but for some weird reason on the emulator and my other phones it works just well. 966/1080*480 for the emulator and the 426 is exactly what we see there.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is interessted why it didnt work. Finally i found out.

Now

```
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.picture)
```

not only loads the pictures but also scales it depending on your resolution ( not always just on some resolution) thats why it confused me. I thought it just loads the damn picture. Now how to solve this:

```
BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opts.inScaled = false;

BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.picture,opts)
```